# Finding the dominant color of an image in an Android @drawable

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, drawable

You can understand why I'm trying to find the dominant color in an image if you use Windows 7.  When your mouse over a program in the taskbar, the background of that particular program changes based on the most dominant color in the icon.  I have noticed this technique used in other programs as well, but can't remember them off the top of my head.

I can see this being helpful in a number of UI techniques that I'm using to develop an application, and I was wondering how finding the most common color would be achieved from an Android drawable resource.

Comment: A new API was added with Lollipop that helps extract prominent colors from a Bitmap. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28145358/1956632) for details. Since the Palette class mentioned is in the support7 library, it should work in older versions of Android as well.

Comment: android v7 palette support lib does that for us.Anyone looking for demo http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/10/android-support-v7-palette-demo.html

Comment: oops, blog does not exist anymore :c

Comment: I know that some Android launchers can sort apps by the color of their icons, That's another example.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

In Android 5.0 Lollipop, a class was added to help extract useful colors from a Bitmap. The [Palette](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html) class, found in android.support.v7.graphics, can extract the following colors:

- Vibrant
- Vibrant Dark
- Vibrant Light
- Muted
- Muted Dark
- Muted Light

This Android training page gives all the details you need to use the class (I tried it myself in Android Studio and it was very straightforward): http://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html#ColorExtract

To quote:

> The Android Support Library r21 and above includes the [Palette](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html)
>   class, which lets you extract prominent colors from an image. To
>   extract these colors, pass a Bitmap object to the Palette.generate()
>   static method in the background thread where you load your images. If
>   you can't use that thread, call the Palette.generateAsync() method and
>   provide a listener instead.*
>
> You can retrieve the prominent colors from the image using the getter
>   methods in the Palette class, such as Palette.getVibrantColor.
>
> To use the Palette class in your project, add the following Gradle
>   dependency to your app's module:
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>     ...
>     implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:21.0.+'
> }
> ```
>
> Or if you're using androidx:
>
> ```
> implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
> ```

**If you need to use generateAsync(), here's how:**

```
Palette.generateAsync(bitmap, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
    public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
        // Do something with colors...
    }
});
```

EDIT:
Since the question asks how to extract colors from a drawable resource, you'd first have to convert the drawable to a bitmap to use the technique I've described. Luckily, that is quite simple using BitmapFactory:

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                       R.drawable.icon_resource);`
```

Comment: If you want to experiment with what colors the Palette class extracts, check out my app on the Play Store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tonyw.sampleapps.palettecolorextraction. You can find the source code for it on GitHub: https://github.com/tony-w/PaletteColorExtraction

Comment: Excellent answer. This makes most of the available libraries and methods redundant.

Comment: Palette.generateAsync method has been deprecated. Use Palette.from(bitmap).generate(paletteListener) instead

Comment: @TonyWickham The `generateAsync` it is now deprecated.
Do you have any idea how to get the color of the favicon from url ?

Comment: @Spritzig use from: 
 `Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new PaletteAsyncListener() {
     public void onGenerated(Palette p) {
         // Use generated instance
     }
 });`

Answer (score 47):

There is also an another solution, it's more approximative but if you don't want to have long delay for searching color, it can do the job.

```
public static int getDominantColor(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 1, 1, true);
    final int color = newBitmap.getPixel(0, 0);
    newBitmap.recycle();
    return color;
}
```

Comment: This is a very helpful answer. I was using the loop method but that was making the UI jerky. Now it's very smooth.

Comment: As of support:palette-v7:25.0.0, this no longer needs a custom method - just use palette.getDominantSwatch().

Comment: It still take some time to be done and need to be done asynchronously.

Comment: i really appreciate your answer. short and sweet

Comment: Well to be fair you dont want to scale a bitmap on the UI thread either. But nice approach nonetheless

Answer (score 14):

To find the ***Dominant*** / Vibrant / Muted color from an image, use [Palette](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/palette/graphics/Palette):

**import:**

```
implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
```

**usage:**

```
    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.image)

    Palette.Builder(bitmap).generate { it?.let {  palette ->
        val dominantColor = palette.getDominantColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.defaultColor))

        // TODO: use dominant color

    } }
```

Comment: last version available on https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/palette

Answer (score 9):

This class iterates through a Bitmap and returns the most dominate colour. 
Feel free to clean up the code where necessary.

```
public class ImageColour {

String colour;


public ImageColour(Bitmap image) throws Exception {

     int height = image.getHeight();
     int width = image.getWidth();

     Map m = new HashMap();

        for(int i=0; i < width ; i++){

            for(int j=0; j < height ; j++){

                int rgb = image.getPixel(i, j);
                int[] rgbArr = getRGBArr(rgb);                

                if (!isGray(rgbArr)) {   

                        Integer counter = (Integer) m.get(rgb);   
                        if (counter == null)
                            counter = 0;
                        counter++;                                
                        m.put(rgb, counter);       

                }                
            }
        }        

        String colourHex = getMostCommonColour(m);
    }



    public static String getMostCommonColour(Map map) {

        List list = new LinkedList(map.entrySet());
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
              public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

                return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue())
                  .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue());

              }

        });    

        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry )list.get(list.size()-1);
        int[] rgb= getRGBArr((Integer)me.getKey());

        return Integer.toHexString(rgb[0])+" "+Integer.toHexString(rgb[1])+" "+Integer.toHexString(rgb[2]);        
    }    


    public static int[] getRGBArr(int pixel) {

        int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
        int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
        int blue = (pixel) & 0xff;

        return new int[]{red,green,blue};

  }

    public static boolean isGray(int[] rgbArr) {

        int rgDiff = rgbArr[0] - rgbArr[1];
        int rbDiff = rgbArr[0] - rgbArr[2];

        int tolerance = 10;

        if (rgDiff > tolerance || rgDiff < -tolerance) 
            if (rbDiff > tolerance || rbDiff < -tolerance) { 

                return false;

            }                

        return true;
    }


public String returnColour() {

    if (colour.length() == 6) {
        return colour.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    } else {
        return "ffffff";
    }
}
```

to get the hex simply call
    `returnColour();`

Comment: I suggest to whoever uses this approach to play with the tolerance variable. Depending on the value you set it the algorithm runs faster or slower.

Answer (score 8):

Add to dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
```

and..

```
 AppCompatImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);

 Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
 Palette.from(bitmap).generate(palette -> {
      int vibrant = palette.getVibrantColor(0x000000); // <=== color you want
      int vibrantLight = palette.getLightVibrantColor(0x000000);
      int vibrantDark = palette.getDarkVibrantColor(0x000000);
      int muted = palette.getMutedColor(0x000000);
      int mutedLight = palette.getLightMutedColor(0x000000);
      int mutedDark = palette.getDarkMutedColor(0x000000);
 });
```

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable`

Answer (score 4):

I wrote my own methods to get dominant color:

**Method 1** (My technique)

1. Reduce to `ARGB_4444` color space
2. Compute the maximum occurrence of individual RGB elements and obtaining 3 distinctive maximum values
3. Combining maximum values to dominant RGB color

   ```
   public int getDominantColor1(Bitmap bitmap) {

   if (bitmap == null)
       throw new NullPointerException();

   int width = bitmap.getWidth();
   int height = bitmap.getHeight();
   int size = width * height;
   int pixels[] = new int[size];

   Bitmap bitmap2 = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444, false);

   bitmap2.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

   final List<HashMap<Integer, Integer>> colorMap = new ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Integer>>();
   colorMap.add(new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());
   colorMap.add(new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());
   colorMap.add(new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());

   int color = 0;
   int r = 0;
   int g = 0;
   int b = 0;
   Integer rC, gC, bC;
   for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
       color = pixels[i];

       r = Color.red(color);
       g = Color.green(color);
       b = Color.blue(color);

       rC = colorMap.get(0).get(r);
       if (rC == null)
           rC = 0;
       colorMap.get(0).put(r, ++rC);

       gC = colorMap.get(1).get(g);
       if (gC == null)
           gC = 0;
       colorMap.get(1).put(g, ++gC);

       bC = colorMap.get(2).get(b);
       if (bC == null)
           bC = 0;
       colorMap.get(2).put(b, ++bC);
   }

   int[] rgb = new int[3];
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       int max = 0;
       int val = 0;
       for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : colorMap.get(i).entrySet()) {
           if (entry.getValue() > max) {
               max = entry.getValue();
               val = entry.getKey();
           }
       }
       rgb[i] = val;
   }

   int dominantColor = Color.rgb(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);

   return dominantColor;
    }
   ```

**Method 2** (Old technique)

1. Reduce to `ARGB_4444` color space
2. Compute the occurrence of each color and finding the maximum one as dominant color

   ```
   public int getDominantColor2(Bitmap bitmap) {
   if (bitmap == null)
       throw new NullPointerException();

   int width = bitmap.getWidth();
   int height = bitmap.getHeight();
   int size = width * height;
   int pixels[] = new int[size];

   Bitmap bitmap2 = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444, false);

   bitmap2.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

   HashMap<Integer, Integer> colorMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

   int color = 0;
   Integer count = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
       color = pixels[i];
       count = colorMap.get(color);
       if (count == null)
           count = 0;
       colorMap.put(color, ++count);
   }

   int dominantColor = 0;
   int max = 0;
   for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : colorMap.entrySet()) {
       if (entry.getValue() > max) {
           max = entry.getValue();
           dominantColor = entry.getKey();
       }
   }
   return dominantColor;
   }
   ```

Comment: question: What is bitmap2 for? you don't seem to use it after copying from the original bitmap.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through all the pixel's color data and average the color values, ignore anything that is a shade of grey or transparent.  I believe that is what Microsoft does in Windows 7 based on a recent blog post.

**edit**
The blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/06/10244432.aspx

This link showing how Chrome picks the dominant color may also be helpful.   http://www.quora.com/Google-Chrome/How-does-Chrome-pick-the-color-for-the-stripes-on-the-Most-visited-page-thumbnails

Comment: I was hoping there would be an API function buried deep somewhere. This is good info

Comment: I found a simple hack: copy as a 1x1 bitmap and get the color: http://aerilys.fr/blog/?p=1341

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers did the job for me, and I didn't rule out the cause of the problem.

This is what I ended up using:

```
public static int getDominantColor(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (bitmap == null) {
        return Color.TRANSPARENT;
    }
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    int size = width * height;
    int pixels[] = new int[size];
    //Bitmap bitmap2 = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444, false);
    bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    int color;
    int r = 0;
    int g = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int a;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        color = pixels[i];
        a = Color.alpha(color);
        if (a > 0) {
            r += Color.red(color);
            g += Color.green(color);
            b += Color.blue(color);
            count++;
        }
    }
    r /= count;
    g /= count;
    b /= count;
    r = (r << 16) & 0x00FF0000;
    g = (g << 8) & 0x0000FF00;
    b = b & 0x000000FF;
    color = 0xFF000000 | r | g | b;
    return color;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Android's pallete generator seems to intentionally avoid getting the most used color