# Get color from wallpaper? - Android

Tags: java, android, colors, widget, wallpaper

How can I find the (Average) color of the current wallpaper and set that color to a layout on my widget?

An example of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

This is a setting on AccuWeather:

[image]

Comment: 1>https://chris.banes.me/2014/07/04/palette-preview/
2>http://willowtreeapps.com/blog/palette-the-new-api-for-android/.
 maybe this can help.

Comment: Fastest method (calculates 1 pixel only after averaging a 1x1 px copy of the bitmap): http://stackoverflow.com/a/29185394/2649012

Answer (score 2):

You can use [WallpaperManager.getWallpaperColors](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getWallpaperColors(kotlin.Int)) that was added in API 27

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get current wallpaper and convert it to bitmap like

```
final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)wallpaperDrawable).getBitmap();
```

After that use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471236/finding-the-dominant-color-of-an-image-in-an-android-drawable) to get dominant color of an image.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Bitmap to find the pixels and you can compare the values to find the average pixels.

For ex-

```
ImageView imageView = ((ImageView)v);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
```

There are many ways you can do this..

Please tell more information what do you want to do?

What you can do is-

get the wallpaper using `WallpaperMAnager.`

Convert it to `Bitmap.`

Get all the pixels Above techniques might help you.

Calculate the average using `pixel arrays.`

Using the average make a color and set your wallpaper to the calculated average color.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying properly. I would want to change the background color of the layout inside my widget whenever the wallpaper is changed on the device. This color would match the color of the wallpaper.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use this to get the wallpaper and transfer it to Bitmap:

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(mContext);
Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable) wallpaperDrawable).getBitmap();
```