# How can I change the background of the screen assuming I have an image and depending on its color I need to change the background?

Tags: android, image, colors, background

Assume I have an image of red color ( mostly red inside image) then, how can I set the background according to that image file with a blur effect.

Comment: check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471236/finding-the-dominant-color-of-an-image-in-an-android-drawable

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Palette API to extract the prominent colors from bitmap images.
Add the following dependency in gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Create the palette object :

```
 Palette.PaletteAsyncListener paletteListener = new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
  public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
    // access palette colors here
  }
}

Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.nyancat);
if (myBitmap != null && !myBitmap.isRecycled()) {
    Palette.from(myBitmap).generate(paletteListener);
}
```

For more detailed process look [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/extracting-colors-to-a-palette-with-android-lollipop/).